# Detect if string includes one expression and excludes another in a Visual Studio RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2013

I am struggling with a file search using a regex.

I'm looking for text files that contain one expression but not another further down the file. I'm struggling with the multiline-ness of it all.

Sample file:

```
Here is a Target Phrase that I want to find and
here is a madeupword that if it is missing 
means that the file is of interest.
```

I want to find files where the expression `Target Phrase` is present but `madeupword` is not present.

I was hoping something along the lines of

```
(Target Phrase)(?![.\s]*madeupword)
```

would be what I need, but no joy....

Ideally this would be a regex that Visual Studio 2013 can process in the "Find in files" dialog, but I'll take a C# regex equivalent I can use in a quick folder scanning console app.

Comment: Try `(Target Phrase)(?![\S\s\r\n]*madeupword)`.

Comment: That looks like it is doing the job in C# - Visual Studio still not succeeding, but that's enough for me. Put that in as a reply and I'll mark as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression in Find dialog in VS to find a string that has `Target Phrase` that is not followed by `madeupword`:

```
(Target Phrase)(?![\s\S\r]*madeupword)
```

In C#, all you need is `(?s)(Target Phrase)(?!.*madeupword)`.

Or this to find that word if it is followed by `madeupword`:

```
(Target Phrase)(?=[\s\S\r]*madeupword)
```

This is the only way I can match newlines in VS2012 *Find ...* dialogs.

Removing `\r` will automatically fail the match.

[image]

Comment: In C#, all you need is `(?s)(Target Phrase)(?!.*madeupword).` `(?s)` singleline mode will force `.` to match a newline.